# How can I refer to a type qualified by module name in Swift 4?

Tags: swift

I have a Swift 4 framework `JSB` which defines a public protocol `Type`. In my framework client code I want to refer to the protocol using a qualified name, `JSB.Type` But I get the following error:

```
File.swift:86:25: error: use of undeclared type 'JSB'
                    public var t: JSB.Type
                                  ^
File.swift:86:25: note: cannot use module 'JSB' as a type
                    public var t: JSB.Type
                                  ^
```

Any idea why? Qualifying a type by its module name has worked for me in the past.

Comment: Just asking the obvious: Do you `import JSB` in the client code?

Comment: Thanks. Sure did. If I leave off `JSB.` then it works.

Comment: `Type` is a reserved keyword for use after a type, e.g `String.Type`; so almost certainly the compiler is thinking you're trying to refer to a metatype `JSB.Type`, so is treating `JSB` as a type, not a module. Whether or not this is intended, I'm not sure. It's certainly not advisable to define types that conflict with keywords (though I know you don't have any choice in this case).

Comment: Thanks @Hamish Let me try that.